# Failing to sort js object by value

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I need to sort my js object. Nothing I have done actually works.

```
obj = [
{id: 1, animal: 'dog'}, 
{id: 2, animal: 'cat'},
{id: 3, animal: 'bird'},
{id: 4, animal: 'tiger'},
{id: 5, animal: 'snake'},
{id: 6, animal: 'gorilla'}];
```

My sort is below.

```
 json['animals'][0].sort((a,b) => {
  let fa = a.animal.toLowerCase();
  let fb = b.animal.toLowerCase();
    if(fa < fb) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(fa> fb) {
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
 });
```

The sort does not return the correct.
Will return `bird,cat,dog etc` others will return `bird,cat,tiger,dog.etc`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Also -> `json['animals'][0]`   Why only element 0?..

Comment: Are you sure `json['animals'][0]` is the array you’ve shown? Simply do `.sort(({ animal: a, animal: b }) => a.localeCompare(b, "en", { sensitivity: "accent" }))`. See [`localeCompare`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Comment: Your code works as it should, but the `sort` function should be called for the entire array, not for an single item.
In addition you can reduce size of the code `obj.sort((a, b) => a.animal.localeCompare(b.animal))`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting this: `json['animals'][0]`? Simply use `obj`.

```js
const zoo=[{id:1,animal:"dog"},{id:2,animal:"cat"},{id:3,animal:"bird"},{id:4,animal:"tiger"},{id:5,animal:"snake"},{id:6,animal:"gorilla"}];

const result = zoo.sort((a, b) => a.animal < b.animal ? -1 :a.animal > b.animal ? 1 : 0);

console.log(result)
```